# Behavior of attribute selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand how wildcard selector in CSS does work?
Consider the following `HTML` markup:

```
<div id="child">
</div>
```

And corresponding CSS:

```
div[id="child"] {border-color: green; }
#child{
    border: 20px solid;
    background: aqua;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I think, that style of `div.child` will be:

```
    border: 20px solid;
    background: aqua;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-color:green;
```

I.e. `border-color:green` just add to a stylesheet of `div.child`. But if we write

```
div[id="child"] {border-color: green!important; }
#child{
    border: 20px solid;
    background: aqua;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

It works like

```
#child{
    border-color: green;
    border: 20px solid;
    background: aqua;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

**Question:** Why we must using `div[id="child"] {border-color: green!important; }` rather than `div[id="child"] { border-color: green }` for applying green color for border?

Comment: What you have is an **attribute selector** not the wildcard selector (which is `*`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an issue of specificity. [**Example demonstrating this.**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/666TB/1/)

Refer to the following documentation:

> **[6.4.3 Calculating a selector's specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity)**
>
> count the number of ID attributes in the selector (= b)
>
> count the number of other attributes and pseudo-classes in the selector (= c)
>
> count the number of element names and pseudo-elements in the selector (= d)

Therefore `#child` has a specificity of 100. And `div[id="child"]` would have a specificity of 11.

Usage of `!important` would effectively override the border applied by `#child`.

Alternatively, you could use the following, and avoid using `!important`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/666TB/)

```
div#child[id="child"] {
    border-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*This doesn't explain the difference between using `!important` and not using it, but rather how to apply the green border without using two rules*.

---

If you look at the documentation for `border:`, you will find this:

> `Formal syntax: <br-width> || <br-style> || <color>`
>
> `<color>`:
> A `<color>` denoting the color of the border. If not set, its default value is the value of the element's `color` property (the text color, not the background color). See border-color.

The default `color` is `#000` (black).

So, by writing

```
border: 20px solid;
```

you are basically specifying:

```
border-width: 20px
border-style: solid;
border-color: #000;
```

And if you put `border-color: green` *before* that rule, it will be overwritten. So you could either write:

```
border: 20px solid;
border-color: green;
```

or

```
border: 20px solid green;
```

Using two rules just to apply the border color is unnecessary.

Comment: 1+ I didn't even consider this. I read the question in a completely different way. ;)

Comment: Well, tbh I'm not sure what the OP is asking for ;) But I can see how it is confusing that the `border-color` property is "ignored" when it looks like that no other color is (explicitly) set.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the specificity of your selector. When there is a conflict between multiple selectors which are trying to apply mutually exclusice styles, specificity is the measure that determines which styles win out.

So your first selector `div[id="child"]` is an attribute/class selector, which has lower specificity than the Id selector from your second block: `#child`

When you apply `!important` to  a style, it is applied irrespective of specificity. It should also be used sparingly for that reason.